# Having a problem with calling and printing out of a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, calling-convention

I am working on a homework assignment in which we are creating a class to be used in a program to be used to do basic math computations either individually or all of the computations at once. So add, subtract, multiply, divide or all four.

I think that the most of the code is good but I cannot get it to print after the user has put their numbers in and selected a somputation method. I have tried print(Week7.addNum), print(Week7.addNum()), print(Week7.addnum(numOne, numTwo)). I get various errors or nothing. With the print(Week7.addnum) I get. I have only been working on the add function and figured if I could get that to work the rest follow suit.

```
class Week7:

    def __init__(self, numOne, numTwo):
        self.numOne = numOne
        self.numTwo = numTwo

    def addNum(self):
        return (self.numOne + self.numTwo)

    def subtNum(self):
        return (self.numOne - self.numTwo)

    def multNum(self):
        return (self.numOne * self.numTwo)

    def divNum(self):
        if self.numTwo !=0:
            return (self.numOne / self.numTwo)
        else:
            return print('You can not divde by 0')

    def allNum(self):
        return (self.numOne + self.numTwo, self.numOne - self.numTwo,     self.numOne * self.numTwo, self.numOne / self.numTwo )



numOne=int(input("Enter first number: "))
numTwo=int(input("Enter second number: "))
functions = [ "1) Add two numbers",
          "2) Mult two numbers",
          "3) Divide two numbers",
          "4) Subtract two numbers",
          "5) All in one: Perform all math Operations",
          "6) End Program" 
        ]
for x in functions:                  
      print( x )
print()


which_Function = int(input("Please select what operation you would like to perform: ") )



if which_Function == 1:
     print(Week7.addNum)

elif which_Function == 2:
     Week7.subtNum(self)

elif which_Function == 3:
     Week7.multNum(self)

elif which_Function == 4:
     Week7.divNum(self)

elif which_Function == 5:
     Week7.allNum(self)

elif which_Function == 6:
     exit
```

I think everything works except for the actual printing of the problem. I want to get "1 + 2 = 3" as an example. I know I need to put the "+" and "=" in the print out but I can figure out where once I get it to print at all.
Thanks in advance.
Dave

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry to say, this is a bit of a mess. I think you need to go back a reread whatever notes you have on how classes and objects are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited code, should work:

```
class Week7:

    def __init__(self, numOne, numTwo):
        self.numOne = numOne
        self.numTwo = numTwo

    def addNum(self):
        return (self.numOne + self.numTwo)

    def subtNum(self):
        return (self.numOne - self.numTwo)

    def multNum(self):
        return (self.numOne * self.numTwo)

    def divNum(self):
        if self.numTwo !=0:
            return (self.numOne / self.numTwo)
        else:
            return print('You can not divde by 0')

    def allNum(self):
        return (self.numOne + self.numTwo, self.numOne - self.numTwo,     self.numOne * self.numTwo, self.numOne / self.numTwo )



numOne=int(input("Enter first number: "))
numTwo=int(input("Enter second number: "))

w7 = Week7(numOne, numTwo)

functions = [ "1) Add two numbers",
          "2) Mult two numbers",
          "3) Divide two numbers",
          "4) Subtract two numbers",
          "5) All in one: Perform all math Operations",
          "6) End Program" 
        ]
for x in functions:                  
      print( x )
print()


which_Function = int(input("Please select what operation you would like to perform: ") )



if which_Function == 1:
     print(w7.addNum())

elif which_Function == 2:
     print(w7.multNum())

elif which_Function == 3:
     print(w7.divNum())

elif which_Function == 4:
     print(w7.subtNum())

elif which_Function == 5:
     print(w7.allNum())

elif which_Function == 6:
     exit()
```

---

Explanation of changes:

- `w7 = Week7(numOne, numTwo)` create an instance of the `Week7` object
- `print(w7.addNum())` call the function and print the output.
- `--ditto--mult-----` etc.

I also changed the order because it did not relate to what was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your class. Try something like:

```
instance = Week7(numOne, numTwo)

if which_Function == 1:
   print(instance.addNum())

elif which_Function == 2:
   print(instance.subtNum())

...
```

The object I named `instance` is what will be passed into the methods as `self`, since it's what you're calling them on. When you look up `instance.addNum`, you'll get a "bound method" object, which passes the argument in for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate this. I knew it was something I was missing somewhere.